# Mount exFAT volume using Paragon exFAT, NTFS & HFS+ app

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, root-access, file-system

Device: Mini-PC RK3188
Android: 4.2.2 jelly bean, rooted

I am using [Paragon exFAT, NTFS & HFS+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.paragon.mounter) to mount and access NTFS and HFS+ volumes.  As it states in the application description, exFAT is available to OEM's only. Does this mean mean I cannot use a 3rd-party Android device? Is there any way to mount an exFAT drive?

Comment: I appreciate your edit, but the root tag does apply as it requires superuser/a rooted device.

Comment: I replaced superuser with root.

Comment: What are these volumes you are talking about? SD cards? USB drives?

Comment: Sounds good.  Well, it could apply to either as your may format both with exFAT.  Specifically it is an external drive, although the ability to mount other exFAT formatted devices would be great.